Copy/Paste and Duplication Differ with Cloth Simulation
I have a baked cloth simulation that looks as follows:

I need to create meshes for each part of the shirt, so I copied and pasted the shirt repeatedly and created a mask for each part of the shirt and exported with no problems.

I tried to script this by leveraging bpy.ops.object.duplicate() and mesh_obj.copy() (the equivalent of "Object > Duplicate Objects"), and I get a very different result:

How do I replicate the exact behavior of copy and paste?
